# Custom Transition to present view controller not working

Tags: ios, animation, presentmodalviewcontroller

In my app i want to slide in and out viewcontroller. So for that i am using custom transition but the app crashes.I am not able to find out what the exact issue is.Please do help me out.

Code

```
class CustomTransition: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning,UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        // get reference to our fromView, toView and the container view that we should perform the transition in
        let container = transitionContext.containerView
        let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.from)! // the app crashes here saying nil founded
        let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.to)!
        let animationDuration = self .transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)
        let offScreenRight = CGAffineTransform(translationX: container.frame.width, y: 0)
        let offScreenLeft = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -container.frame.width, y: 0)

        toView.transform = offScreenRight

        // add the both views to our view controller
        container.addSubview(toView)
        container.addSubview(fromView)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: [] , animations: {
            fromView.transform = offScreenLeft
            toView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }, completion: { finished in
            // tell our transitionContext object that we've finished animating
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        })
    }

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 1
    }

    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
    }

    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
    }
}
```

How i am using

```
let vc = self.getViewControllerFromStoryBoard(storyBoardName: FORGOT_PASSWORD_SB, identifier: FORGOT_PASSWORD_IDENTIFIER) as! ForgotPassword
let a = CustomTransition()
vc.transitioningDelegate = a
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The app crashes `let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.from)!` saying that nil founded.
Am i missing out something?

Comment: How do you present your view controller?

Comment: @NSDmitry i have mentioned in how i am using

Answer (score 0):

Due to API changes in Apple in iOS 13 update. I was facing same problem Add this line fixed my issue.

> vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen